# Can an equation containing a specific tensor be Lorentz invariant?

Tags: tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry, covariance

Let $A_u$ be a vector field in spacetime. If we restrict to a $2+1$ spacetime, and define the Levi-Civita tensor $\epsilon^{uvp}$ by $\epsilon^{123}=1$, then is the following equation Lorentz invariant?

\begin{equation*}
\epsilon^{uvp}\partial_uA_p+mA^v=0.
\end{equation*}

I checked that it transforms covariantly under a Lorentz transformation. Thus, because the specific tensor $\epsilon^{uvp}$ is invariant, the whole equation can be claimed to be Lorentz invariant. Is my argument correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The only caveat is that it is invariant only under proper Lorentz transformations.

Comment: @Prahar Can you expand on how an equation can be *invariant* when there are free indices?  Invariant means it doesn't change under transformation, so if it is covariant - i.e. if it changes in the right way under transformation - how can it be invariant.

Comment: Because its a very special tensor. You can ask the same question about the metric tensor $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. How does it remain invariant if its a tensor? It does because it is a special type of tensor. Not all tensors have this property. But the metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ and Levi-Civita tensor $\varepsilon_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_d}$ have such invariance properties.

Comment: @Prahar right, $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is invariant but $\eta_{\mu\nu}A^\nu$ isn't.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero  - I never said it was.

Comment: @Prahar I clearly need to refresh my memory on tensors.

Comment: @Prahar what do you mean by a proper transformation? And it there is an arbitrary tensor in the place of levi civita tensor, then is the equation not lorentz invariant because there is a preferred reference frame by the tensor?(Of course the equation itself transforms covariantly with a arbitrary tensor).

Comment: @Keith - See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The metric tensor is a special tensor that is invariant under Lorentz transformations. This is of course trivial to see due to the very definition. Under Lorentz transformations
$$
\eta_{\mu\nu} \to \eta_{\rho\sigma} \Lambda^\rho{}_\mu \Lambda^\sigma{}_\nu.
$$
But due to the property of Lorentz transformations, the above is just $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ so that 
$$
\eta_{\mu\nu} \to \eta_{\rho\sigma} \Lambda^\rho{}_\mu \Lambda^\sigma{}_\nu = \eta_{\mu\nu}.
$$
Thus $\eta$ is Lorentz invariant.

Similarly, the Levi-Civita tensor is invariant. Under Lorentz transformations
$$
\varepsilon_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_d} \to \varepsilon_{\nu_1 \cdots \nu_d} \Lambda^{\mu_1}{}_{\nu_1} \cdots \Lambda^{\mu_d}{}_{\nu_d}
$$
But now, due to the definition of the epsilon tensor and the definition of determinant of matrix (see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Determinants)), the above is equal to
$$
\varepsilon_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_d} \to \varepsilon_{\nu_1 \cdots \nu_d} \Lambda^{\mu_1}{}_{\nu_1} \cdots \Lambda^{\mu_d}{}_{\nu_d} = (\det \Lambda)\varepsilon_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_d}.
$$
However, we know that $\det \Lambda = \pm 1$. Thus, $\varepsilon$ is invariant under proper Lorentz transformations (which have $\det \Lambda =1$) but picks up a sign under improper Lorentz transformations.

Thus, the equation you have in the problem is invariant under proper Lorentz transformations but not under the improper ones such as parity or time reversals.

PS - It looks like you got that equation trying to solve massive CS theories and the CS action is famously parity non-invariant.

Comment: In many cases just SO(1,3) seems to be considered as the lorentz group, that is boosts and rotations. In that case is there no problem?

Comment: If that's all you're interested in then there is no problem. That's not to say that there is a problem if you are talking about parity. It's just that in that case, these equations are not parity invariant.

Comment: man I'm sorry to bother you with this... I don't have a problem with the $\epsilon$ tensor being *invariant* but clearly $mA^\nu$ is NOT Lorentz-invariant, it's "merely" covariant (unless all $A^\nu$ are $0$).  So given this, how can $\epsilon^{u\nu p}\partial_u A_p$ be *invariant* when it's just equal to -$mA^\nu$, which is NOT invariant?

Comment: I am not saying each individual term is invariant. What I said was "The equation is invariant" which means "In a Lorentz transformed frame, the equation takes the same form as it does here". This is what those words mean. Each term in that equation itself is covariant. The entire equation is invariant because it is equal to 0.

Comment: I suddenly wonder what the solution of this equation would be. What kind of particle does this equation describe?

Comment: massive gauge field in 3d

Comment: Oh I  made a typo in the index of epsilon. I am dealing with 1+2 spacetime so the index of epsilon should be $\epsilon^{012}$. Weren't you confused  by this? Does 3d in your comment mean 1+2? Or does it mean just spatial?

Comment: So, does your answer that levi civita tensor is invariant under proper lorentz transformation hold for 1+3 dimension, which implies that the same invariance holds for 1+2 dimension?

Comment: My answer does not depend on the dimension or signature of the spacetime. It holds in every dimension for every metric. When I say 3d I usually mean 1+2d. Also, I wasn't confused because I know the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's helpful to note that the equation can be rewritten in terms of differential forms without any indices at all.

Write $A$ for the $1$-form $A = A_\mu dx^\mu$.  Denote by $\star$ the [Hodge star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) map which sends $p$-forms to $3-p$ forms.  $\star$ acts on $2$-forms by replacing $dt \wedge dx$ with $dy$, $dx \wedge dy$ with $dt$, and so forth.

In this notation, your equation is $*dA + mA = 0$.